# Are there any modern Nestorian or Jacobite systematic theology textbooks?

Tags: systematic-theology, nestorianism

There exist many modern (say, 20th century or later), English language systematic theology textbooks from a Western Christian perspective. For example, *Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma* by Ludwig Ott from a Catholic perspective and *Systematic Theology: An Introduction to Biblical Doctrine* by Wayne Grudem from a Reformed perspective would surely count as being such.

Does there exist analogous, English language texts that take the perspective of Nestorian or Jacobite Christians?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. One note on your question: you may want to specify which languages you speak, because it's quite likely that any systematic theology that exists for these traditions hasn't been translated into English.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Thank you for the tip: I went ahead and updated my question to be more explicit about the language. Thanks for the kind welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering with respect to the Nestorians/Assyrian church of the East rather than the Jacobites (Miaphysites):

While not exactly a modern text, the [Marganitha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marganitha) (13th Century) is a Assyrian (a.k.a. Nestorian) systematic theology in good esteem. There is a fairly readable 19th century translation into English in the public domain [provided on wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Nestorians_and_their_Rituals/Volume_2/Appendix_B).

Unfortunately, I doubt there would be any more modern examples, especially given the history of the Assyrian church. Before the 20th century, there would be little motivation to write a systematic theology in the English language. During the 1920s, they suffered a genocide under the Ottomans (The so-called *Seyfo*), and the subsequent emigrations meant that the immediate pastoral concerns of reorganizing a previously geographically isolated church on a global scale (in foreign cultures no less) were of more importance than writing systematic theology. Likewise, recent [ecumenical efforts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Christological_Declaration_Between_the_Catholic_Church_and_the_Assyrian_Church_of_the_East), which by their nature tend to involve looking *back* at historical theological positions rather than creating new works, may account for the lack of such a systematic theology.

A Modern (2006) Assyrian *Catechism* (rather than systematic theology) [can be found here](https://bethkokheh.assyrianchurch.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/catechism-of-the-Church-of-the-East-edited-in-the-year-2020.pdf) by C. Klutz and G. Toma. It has a Bibliography which includes the above-mentioned Marganitha, as well as a number of other volumes, which may be of interest, though they do not all appear to be in English.